# Why doesn't TypeScript type check arithmetic operations?

Tags: typescript

Why does TypeScript not throw a type missmatch in the following?

```
undefined * 1 === NaN
```

Implementing a type-check for it would be trivial:

```
(n : number, m : number) => number
```

Would it also be possible to implement one for the `+` operator?

Comment: But `undefined * 1` is a valid javascript statement, why would the compiler have any issues with that?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Sure, but personally I'd want TypeScipt to try to prevent me from ever producing `NaN`.

Comment: Because ... Javascript :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is defined as a superset of JavaScript. Restricting that operation would forbid using otherwise valid JS code in TS.

> Sure, but personally I'd want TypeScipt to try to prevent me from ever producing NaN

`NaN` is kind of a special case, because while "not a number" in the name, it still lies in the domain of the Number type (mostly because of underlying IEEE-754 implementation). Either way, you can construct your own stricter types (e.g. wrapping Number) if you need/want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really safe guard against getting a `NaN` value based on the compiler, here's an example:

```
function mul(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x * y;
}

function getDataFromServer(): Promise<number> {
    // async request which returns a number
}

getDataFromServer().then(num => mul(num, 2));
```

The compiler has no way of knowing what the server will return.
It might be a number, it might be a string representation of a number (`"2"`), it might even be `"internal server error"`.
You can check for those things at runtime in your code, but the compiler can't figure that statically.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this answers the question. The implementation of `getDataFromServer` needs to guarantee that whatever server returned either forms a number, or signal promise error. That's how the compiler figures that statically. It has nothing to do with the OP asking about numerical operators not having stricter signatures.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz As I wrote in my answer, the developer needs to make sure, inside the implementation of `getDataFromServer` that it returns a `number`, but I was trying to show that the compiler can't possibly know whether it will be a `number`, `NaN` or something else.

Comment: Well, so what? The data from a socket will be typically typed as a "buffer" or a "string" (which you could create by other means). What does that have to do with mathematical operators' signatures?

Comment: Well, your answer was answered by me as a comment: `"undefined * 1 is a valid javascript statement"` which suffice, but I also wanted to show the OP that the compiler can NOT know that, it's a runtime thing.